# Отмена валидации

Tags: ruby-on-rails, валидация

Пытаюсь отменить валидацию, сделал в модели:

```
before_validation :check_password

def check_passwd
    if password.blank? and not new_record?
        self._validators.delete(:password)
        logger.debug self._validators.to_s
    end
end
```

В лог выводится `_validators` без валидации пароля, а пустой пароль всё равно подвергается валидации. Почему так, что нужно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before_validation :check_password, if: lambda { password.blank? and persisted? }
```

Comment: А разница, лог же выводится, значит проблема не в if а где-то ещё.

Comment: отменить всю валидацию вообще можно лишь указав `save(validate: false)`. Можно отменить какой-то отдельный пункт валидации, также указав `if:`